# Python 3 : detect ajax queries

Tags: python, ajax

I try to scrape some websites with the help of Python and BeautifulSoup.
When a website uses an ajax query with this kind of URL:

https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/tc/v1/magazine?page=2&_embed=true,

I can get the JSON content and analyze it. 
But how can I detect this links to automatically execute a query to get the JSON content?

Thanks,
Rata

Comment: What's the problem? Is it that the URL doesn't end in `.json`, so it doesn't know to grab it?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using the *requests* library in addition to BeautifulSoup, if you aren't already.

Assuming you have a reliable way to scrape these urls, you can do something like:

```
    import requests

    # ...

    response = requests.get('https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/tc/v1/magazine?page=2&_embed=true')

    try:
      json_response = response.json()
      # GET request returned a JSON response
      # ...

    except ValueError:
      # GET request did not return JSON response
      # ...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually this part of the work is ok. What i can't achieve is to automatically find the link. How can i know the existence of 'https://techcrunch.com/wp-json/tc/v1/magazine?page=2&_embed=true' without manually check ?

Comment: Ah. In that case, I would do something like:

    soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html)
    for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
        # do something with requests.get(link['href'])

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll try it.

Comment: Sure thing, let me know if anything's still unclear. That didn't format as well as I'd hoped it would.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I can know find my link and get the json content automatically !